# Rcpp debug in Rstudio with lldb

Tags: r, rstudio, rcpp

The Jim Hester YouTube video [video](https://www.jimhester.com/post/2019-04-05-lldb-debugging/) looks like a potentially really helpful way to put breakpoints in Rcpp code that passes some variables in unexpected ways. However, when I follow the start up directions (Rstudio console copied below) it fails with a message that is not helpful to a new user of lldb.

```
gcn@GCN-MacBook-Pro-7 ISIMIPData % R -d lldb
(lldb) target create "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/exec/R"
Current executable set to '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/exec/R' (x86_64).
(lldb) run
error: process exited with status -1 (attach failed (Not allowed to attach to process.  Look in the console messages (Console.app), near the debugserver entries when the attached failed.  The subsystem that denied the attach permission will likely have logged an informative message about why it was denied.))
(lldb)
```

The Console.app output that I could find is not very useful.

A later post [post](https://www.jimhester.com/post/2018-08-22-debugging-rstudio/) describes an updated process but it too fails in a similar way. I'm using Rstudio version 1.4.1717 with R version 4.1.

Comment: This question is entirely about `lldb` and `RStudio` so maybe the RStudio Community forum is a better bet.  I debug mostly with `gdb` and the older video by the R and BioConductor Core team member Seth Falcon still applies:  https://vimeo.com/11937905 (and do not worry that it is 11 years old: some things simply remain true).

Comment: Also, if I may, a nag: Could you maybe look at your August 20 post I answered and accept the questions if it suits?

Comment: Comment accepted. I have been lost in a different problem for about a month on and off and got distracted. Related to debugger options, I though I had seen that gdb doesn't exist for macs but that turns out to be wrong so I'll check out the vimeo file. Xcode seems like an obvious choice but I can't seem to find directions on how to get set up with cpp code.

Comment: `gdb` and `lldb` should be similar and are both fairly ... old school.  If you compile with `clang++` then `lldb` will be for you.  Usage is "generic": there is no secret Rcpp sauce so any tutorial should help.